# Showing fields as readonly in Edit Form of List Item in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, listitem

I have a list which has 5 columns in it. Some of these fields help the user fill in the data but I don't want the user to modify these fields.

I have tried changing the field to readonly but that ends up hiding the field completely from the form. Is there a way to get the field to render out to the form as just text?

Maybe I need to use javascript to disable the fields programmatically - would prefer not to go down that route though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define your own RenderingTemplate that will [use your own, custom ListFieldIterator](http://g-m-a-c.blogspot.com/2008/04/customizing-sharepoint-2007-forms.html). (an excellent article)